# Store static environment in chunks

Tags: c++, opengl

I have terrain separated by chunks and I would like to put environment (For example, rocks, trees, etc..) in each chunk randomly.

My question is related to how to implement such system in OpenGL.

What I have tried:

1. **Solution**: Draw the environment with instancing once for *all* the terrain (not a specific chunk)

   **Problem**: I except the chunk to sometimes take a bit to load and because I am using threads the environment will appear as floating.
2. **Solution**: Draw the environment with instancing for each chunk.

   **Problem**: To draw each chunk, I will need to bind the VBO for the chunk, draw the chunk, bind the VBO for the environment (and the VAO probably) and draw it.

   I don't want to put so many glBindBuffer functions because I heard it is slow (Please correct me if I am wrong)
3. **(Not tried) Solution**: Somehow merge the vertices of the terrain with its environment and draw them together.

   **Problem:** My terrain is drawn with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP so this is a first problem, the second problem(?) is that I don't know how well it will function (talking speed).

I tried looking up solutions on the internet but didn't seem to find any that relate to chunks.

Anyone know how other games that uses chunks do that? Is there a way to do it without causing a lot of speed decrease?

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Overflow and might be better suited for [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or [computergraphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For improvements on your first proposed solution, you can use a simple mutex or RCU to update things while not affecting the main rendering task.